# "TAG" Extension File?

Tags: extension

I've NEVER seen this before! I'm migrating an EE site from one server to another and am getting this error:

```
error

Unable to load the following extension file:

ext.tag.php
```

I'm running EE version 2.4 and am planning on upgrading, but need to get everything working like it was on the previous server first.

When I set `$config['allow_extensions'] = "n";` everything works fine, but when I re-enable my Extensions I get that error.

I've updated the config file from an `Envee` config to my stock config.php file and still getting that error.

I've downloaded all of the `third_party` folders and did a search for "ext.tag.php" (along with tag.php, etc...) but for the life of me I cannot figure out where that file is being called from.

Has anyone seen this? A Google, Devot-ee and EESE search comes up with nothing really helpful. Hopefully someone else has ran into this before! I have verified that the DB settings are correct and just strange that I can't figure out where this is being called from.

Comment: So for whatever reason the previous DEV is pulling in add-ons from other websites on the same server. I didn't even know you could do that unless you symlinked it or something! So I'm cleaning all of that up!

Comment: Turns out there are a LOT more addons that were being pulled from another site on the server...so I'm in the process of moving all of those addons to the current web folder and hopefully that will do it now that I'm using a fresh config! AY YII YIII Thank heavens for the Developer Log to help pinpoint some of these issues :)

Comment: Must be a Friday afternoon with all of the helpful devs hanging out in this thread ;-)

Comment: It's quite lovely! :D Cleaning up after this dev however is not...New Castle to the rescue!

Comment: Mark, could you please pick an answer below as the solution so this can be moved out of the "unanswered questions" queue? Thanks!

Comment: Done! Sorry about that :) I hate it when people don't mark anything as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got access to the database (command line or phpMyAdmin), take a look at the exp_extensions table and see if you can find something for "tag" there.

There are a few columns in that table with helpful clues; it should reveal what add-on it is (perhaps Solspace Tag?), and, there's a column you should be able to change to disable it independently of the other add-ons.

Hopefully that's enough to get you pointed in the right direction; would be interested to know what the problem turns out to be.

Comment: Now I'm seeing other extensions the site is looking for like SnippetSync. I copied the files over to the websites' third party folder but it's still giving me an error. How would you recommend removing these extensions from the DB? Do I just simply delete the tables?

Comment: Disabling them by setting enabled = n for each of the extensions in question would be the first step, and hopefully that solves the problems. If you've still got issues after that, you're getting into territory that's difficult to give advise on without being able to review things further, I think.

Comment: Hmm yeah that may be the best bet. I'm downloading all of the addons being shared and going to migrate those over one by one. That should do the trick too...good times for a Friday!

Answer (score 3):

It's the Tag module from Solspace. If you've removed the files without uninstalling properly via the control panel, you'll need to delete the 'Tag_ext' rows from 'exp_extensions' in your database.

Answer (score 2):

Solspace has a tag add-on which most likely includes this extension. The error is telling you the same thing you found through your search. That is, the file isn't there. However, it's still being called from the DB. The easiest way to fix this is to simply upload the tag add-on and then do what you need with it from there. If you no longer have it, then you will have to remove it manually through the DB. This will likely include remnants of the extension as well as the module.